# Select from SQL Server database with specific range using textbox

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

```
Try
    conn = New SqlConnection(strcon)
    conn.Open()
    Dim str As String = "select * from MYTABLE where Year >='#" & Txtfromyear_reprt.Text & "#' and Year <='#" & Txttoyear_reprt.Text & "#'"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(str, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "MYTABLE")
    DgvReport.DataSource = ds.Tables("MYTABLE")
    da.Dispose()
    conn.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I'm working with my school project but I've encountered a problem in which I can't solve. I wrote this code in my search button but when I click it at runtime, no data is displayed in my datagrid.

What I want is when I click it I want to display all the data from mytable to the Datagrid view using two textboxes. I have two textboxes, `txtfromyear` and `txttoyear` and a database column `Year` with a datatype `nvarchar(50)`.

Please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure that there is data in your table between these year values ?

Comment: I dont know VB so can you tell me what the '#' characters are needed for ?

Comment: Are you using webforms? IF that query is correct (I'm also wondering about those #), then you only need a DgvReport.DataBind() after setting the DataSource.

Comment: @GuidoG yes,
should i use % then instead of #? because both are not working

Comment: that depends on your datatype, is it a varchar or something else ? Also what database are you using ?

Comment: @RenatoAfonso I'm using windowsforms,

Comment: @GuidoG the datatype is nvarchar(50) and i'm using sql server 2012

Comment: why in the world do you use varchar to store a year or a date ? There is your first problem, fix that first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation to build your sql queries, NEVER!

You are open for sql injection, there is no excuse for it. Instead use sql parameters:

```
Dim dateFrom as Date
Dim dateTo as Date
Dim validFromDate = Date.TryParse(Txtfromyear_reprt.Text.Trim(), dateFrom)
Dim validToDate = Date.TryParse(Txttoyear_reprt.Text.Trim(), dateTo)
```

Now exit this method with a meaningful message if the user didn't provide valid dates. You can check `validFromDate` and `validToDate` which are booleans. The rest of the code is executed `If validFromDate AndAlso validToDate`:

```
Dim str As String = "select * from MYTABLE where Year >= @fromyear and Year <= @toyear"
da = New SqlDataAdapter(str, conn)
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@fromyear", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateFrom 
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@toyear", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTo
' now you can use da.Fill(ds, "MYTABLE") safely
```

---

I just saw you use `varchar` to store `datetimes`. Why? Fix it in the database.